# During debugging I have noticed my code breaks when loading assets or while instantiating gameObject in for loop. There is no error in the code

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, augmented-reality

I wanted to instantiate GameObject with UI elements and wanted to populate data in it.

I have tried running the code in the for loop in separate function or coroutine. I have also tried to copy for loop inside the Firebase logic. Even then it's not working. The only thing worked was when I put the code above the Firebase logic.

```
IEnumerator DoShowSomeProducts(Category category)
  {

      searchText.text = category.name;

       foreach (Transform each in GetComponentInChildren<LayoutGroup>().transform)
    {
        GameObject.Destroy(each.gameObject);
    }

    // parse product
    List<Item> productsInCategory = new List<Item>();
    //Tried the for loop logic here works well but didn't need it here.
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Product").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("There is a fault");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snap = task.Result;
            if (snap.ChildrenCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in snap.Children)
                {
                    print("Creating Item");
                    Item _item = new Item();
                    _item.url = child.Child("url").Value.ToString();
                    _item.image = child.Child("img").Value.ToString();
                    _item.code = child.Child("code").Value.ToString();
                    _item.price = child.Child("price").Value.ToString();
                    _item.category = child.Child("category").Value.ToString();
                    _item.descr = child.Child("descr").Value.ToString();
                    _item.link = child.Child("link").Value.ToString();
                    _item.name = child.Child("name").Value.ToString();
                    print("================================= \n Product\n" + _item.url + "\n" + _item.image + "\n" + _item.code + "\n" + _item.price
                          + "\n" + _item.category + "\n" + _item.descr + "\n" + _item.link + "\n" + _item.name + "\n===========================");


                    productsInCategory.Add(_item);
                    //Here tried to run the for loop logic using separate functions and co-routines.
                    print("Added Product");
                    Debug.Log(_item.category);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < productsInCategory.Count; i++)
    {
        print("PinCat Count = " + productsInCategory.Count);
        Item item = productsInCategory[i];
        GameObject obj = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/ProductButtonPrefab");//this line breaks the code
        GameObject clone = GameObject.Instantiate(obj);//this line brreaks the code.
        clone.transform.parent = GetComponentInChildren<LayoutGroup>().transform;
        clone.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().nameText.text = item.name;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().product = item;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().categoryText.text = item.category;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().priceText.text = item.price;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().nameText.text = item.name;
        print("Know Downloading Image");
        WWW www = new WWW(item.image);
        yield return www;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().mainImage.sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));

    }
    yield break;
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a description of a problem that we can help you with. Also, **you never asked a question**.  You told a story: you wrote some code, it's not working.  Do you have a *specific question that has an answer*?

Comment: Sharing your expected results and actual results will help us narrow down what problems you are having. If you are looking for general code review and fixing, forums like gamedev.net may be more useful.

Comment: @CoryB Ideally the app should be displaying the products on the screen. But right now it's only showing a blank screen.

Comment: so apparently the image download fails -> image without a sprite is just white by default. You should debug that using `if(www.error) Debug.LogError(www.error);` and you should consider using [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) since `WWW` is obsolete. And actually I don't see where you tell the Coroutine to wait until you get a result from firebase so the `for` loops is actually executed before results are there I guess

Answer (score 0):

Your Coroutine doesn't wait until firebase has a result so the `for` loop is always executed before any results from firebase have reached

=> no items are generated since `productsInCategory` is always an empty list.

(also compare [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153928/wait-until-a-method-finish))

---

You should split up the two things into separate methods. Something like

```
public void DoShowSomeProducts(Category category)
{
    searchText.text = category.name;

    foreach (Transform each in GetComponentInChildren<LayoutGroup>().transform)
    {
        GameObject.Destroy(each.gameObject);
    }

    // parse product
    List<Item> productsInCategory = new List<Item>();
    //Tried the for loop logic here works well but didn't need it here.
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Product").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("There is a fault");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snap = task.Result;
            if (snap.ChildrenCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in snap.Children)
                {
                    print("Creating Item");
                    Item _item = new Item();
                    _item.url = child.Child("url").Value.ToString();
                    _item.image = child.Child("img").Value.ToString();
                    _item.code = child.Child("code").Value.ToString();
                    _item.price = child.Child("price").Value.ToString();
                    _item.category = child.Child("category").Value.ToString();
                    _item.descr = child.Child("descr").Value.ToString();
                    _item.link = child.Child("link").Value.ToString();
                    _item.name = child.Child("name").Value.ToString();
                    print("================================= \n Product\n" + _item.url + "\n" + _item.image + "\n" + _item.code + "\n" + _item.price
                          + "\n" + _item.category + "\n" + _item.descr + "\n" + _item.link + "\n" + _item.name + "\n===========================");


                    productsInCategory.Add(_item);
                    //Here tried to run the for loop logic using separate functions and co-routines.
                    print("Added Product");
                    Debug.Log(_item.category);
                }

                // pass the list to the download routine
                StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(productsInCategory));
            }
        }
    });
}

private IEnumerator DownloadImages(List<Item> productsInCategory)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < productsInCategory.Count; i++)
    {
        print("PinCat Count = " + productsInCategory.Count);
        Item item = productsInCategory[i];
        GameObject obj = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/ProductButtonPrefab");
        GameObject clone = GameObject.Instantiate(obj);
        clone.transform.parent = GetComponentInChildren<LayoutGroup>().transform;
        clone.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().nameText.text = item.name;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().product = item;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().categoryText.text = item.category;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().priceText.text = item.price;
        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().nameText.text = item.name;
        print("Know Downloading Image");
        WWW www = new WWW(item.image);
        yield return www;

        // you should always debug things
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Download failed for item {0} at index {1} due to: {2}", item.name, i, www.error);
            continue;
        }

        clone.GetComponent<ProductButton>().mainImage.sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
    }
}
```

---

Also you said `// this line breaks the code` for

```
GameObject obj = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/ProductButtonPrefab");
```

this lines assumes your object resides in `"Assets/Resources/Prefabs/ProductButtonPrefab"` so make sure it is inside the [Resources folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html)

(That the next line also fails is obvious since you can't `Instantiate(obj)` if `obj` is `null` due to the previous line)

But why loading it from `Resources` at all and everytime again? Either load it only once before the for loop (or even better on game start)

```
GameObject itemPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/ProductButtonPrefab");

for (int i = 0; i < productsInCategory.Count; i++)
{
     print("PinCat Count = " + productsInCategory.Count);
     Item item = productsInCategory[i];

     GameObject clone = GameObject.Instantiate(itemPrefab);
     // ...
}
```

or diectly put it into the "normal" assets and reference it in a field like

```
public GameObject ItemPrefab;
```